# How to get sum of column in matrix report in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

How to get sum of column in matrix report(in SSRS) based on group by in SSRS report.

In SSRS report, how to get sum of coulmn for matrix report.

Answer (score 1):

add a header to the column group and then simply use `=SUM(Fields!mySumfield.Value)` in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column name to do sum in matrix report and bind the total field like below:

```
=IIF(Fields!ColumnName.Value <>"Total Count", ("$"& SUM(CDec(Fields!Value.Value))) , (SUM(CDec(Fields!Value.Value))))
```